# Why should I skip the first episode of Gungrave?

Tags: gungrave

I've seen advice on the internet indicating that one should start watching Gungrave at episode 2, and possibly come back to episode 1 at some later point in the series.

Before I start watching this show, I would like to know whether this advice makes sense. In a spoiler-free way, can someone explain why I should skip episode 1? (Feel free to include more detailed explanations in a spoiler block.)

And should I come back to episode 1 at some later point in the series?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first episode is almost exactly like the eighteenth episode. What it does is confuse the viewer with out of context content in addition to spoiling a lot of the anime.

Many animes like to show an ambiguous later scene in the first episode, and then build towards that story line, like in Psycho-pass. Gungrave is an example of where this failed miserably. The episode is detailed to the point where it is just plain confusing and spoiled.

It's best to watch episode 1 after episode 17.

Comment: would you then watch Episode 18? or skip it entirely?

Comment: @Memor-X Yeah, I would watch 2-17, 1, then 18 despite 1 and 18 being nearly identical. If you had to choose between 1 and 18 however, choose 18 and skip 1. Gungrave decided to take 95% of episode 18 and put it into episode 1.

Comment: I watched Gungrave without reading first. And I agree with this. I would go so far to say that ep1 ruined it for me totally.